# Datagridview not Updating Datasource

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am using Windows Form Application. I have created on form for listing and on Add button I have create new window. When new record is adding datasource is updating but gridview not displaying last added record. Why this is happening?

```
public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindCompanyData();
    }

 public void BindCompanyData()
    {
        List<CompanyListModel> companyListModel = new List<CompanyListModel>();
        companyListModel =  _obiClient.GetCompanies();
        companyDataGrid.DataSource = null;
        companyDataGrid.DataSource = companyListModel;
        companyDataGrid.Refresh();
        companyDataGrid.CellClick += new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(DatGridCell_Click);
    }

private void btn_addCompany_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CompanyAddEdit companyAddEdit = new CompanyAddEdit();
        companyAddEdit.ShowForm();
    }
```

On button add It open new form. and on close that form I have called `BindCompanyData()` method.

```
 private void btn_save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string selectedItem = cmbbx_companyType.SelectedItem.ToString();            
        WriteXML(selectedItem);
        this.Close();
        MainForm mainForm = new MainForm();
        mainForm.BindCompanyData();
    }
```

What is missing?

Comment: If you click the btn_addCompany in your main window then a small window opens in which the company type should be selected and this information is not updated in the main window?

Comment: Then what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is you are running `BindCompanyData();` on newly created form with your code:

```
MainForm mainForm = new MainForm();
mainForm.BindCompanyData();
```

What you should do is inside `CompanyAddEdit` constructor request for `MainForm form` parameter and pass your current form which you use in button. So your code look like this:

```
//Inside CompanyAddEdit form
class CompanyAddEdit : Form
{
    MainForm passedForm;

    public CompanyAddEdit(MainForm form)
    {
        this.passedForm = form;
    }
    //other code
    private void btn_save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string selectedItem = cmbbx_companyType.SelectedItem.ToString();            
        WriteXML(selectedItem);
        this.Close();

        passedForm.BindCompanyData();
   }
}



//Inside main form
private void btn_addCompany_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CompanyAddEdit companyAddEdit = new CompanyAddEdit(this);
    companyAddEdit.ShowForm();
}
```

Comment: @SrustiThakkar Glad i helped :)